# No errors but PowerShell code not working

Tags: powershell, csv

No errors in this script, but I am scratching my head because I have checked the csv data and the first and last names match up just fine (so no error should be written to the log). Yet, instead of skipping the writing to the log, it always does. So, I had to Comment out the Continue line or the script won't finish.

Also, I want to enable a user object if the re-hire date is 8 days in the future from todays date, but this also appears to not work (no obvious errors to me). Can someone please check my logic? This is not the full script, just the areas where I can't find any issues. Thanks

```
`$CSVLine = "C:\scripts\adp\Test ADP Import spec.csv"
$ErrorLog = "C:\scripts\adp\ADPProcessErrors.csv"
[xml]$DivLocFile = Get-Content -Path "C:\Scripts\adp\DivLocData.xml"
$DocumentRoot = $DivLocFile.DocumentElement
$UserLocationCode = @{}
$a = Get-Date

ForEach ($row in (Import-Csv $CSVLine)) {

    #Skips over Terminiated employees
If ($CSVLine.EmployeeStatus -eq "Terminated") { Continue }
    #Gets the user's First and Last name
    $User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter ("(sAMAccountName=" + $Row.sAMAccountName + ")") -Properties *

    If ($User -eq $Null) {
        #If there is no First and Last name this will throw an error and go on to the next record.
        ($Row.sAMAccountName + ",AD Object Not Found") | Out-File -FilePath $ErrorLog -Append

        Continue
         }  
        #Checks whether First or Last names don't match
        If (($User.givenName -ne $CSVLine.'First Name') -or ($User.sn -ne $CSVLine.'Last Name')) { 

        ($Row.sAMAccountName + ",givenName and sn property mismatch") | Out-File -FilePath $ErrorLog -Append

        #Continue
         }
        #Enables a disabled user if they have a hire date 8 days in advance of today's date. 
        If (($CSVLine.'Date of hire/rehire' -gt ($a)) -and ($CSVLine.'Date of hire/rehire') -le ($a.AddDays(8)) -and (!($User.Enabled)))  {

        (Set-ADUser -Enabled $True -Identity $User)
        ("SID:" + $Row.sAMAccountName + ", User:[" + $User.givenName + " " + $User.sn + "] Re-Hire date is in range. Account enabled.") | Out-File -FilePath $ErrorLog -Append
        }`
```

Comment: Looks like a lot of your IF statements are using $CSVLine where it looks like they should instead be using $row ?

Comment: You are correct! I figured that out shortly after posting this. Now if I could just figure out why the Enable a Disabled account block won't work after that change?

Comment: How do I mark your response as correct Campbell.rw?

Comment: I could add it as an answer and you could mark it as correct I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a lot of your IF statements are using $CSVLine where it looks like they should instead be using $row